# How to calculate height in CSS

Tags: css

I want to create a placeholder with CSS if an image is not present. There are 4 images in a row on a mobile device. The width is easy:

```
.placeholder {
background: red;
display: block;
float: left;
margin: 0px 1px 0px 0px;
width: calc(100%/4 - 1px);
height: 80px;
}
```

I know that the images are 1.25 aspect ratio. So it should be possible to calculate the height. If one uses the same command like for width, the hight will be used as base for the 100% and not the width.

Is there a solution with CSS for this problem?

Comment: An interesting tutorial: https://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/ and here: http://vincentp.me/blog/use-cases-for-calc

Comment: A nice workaround to create perfectly squared divs is to just set width as liked and then setting `padding-bottom:100%`which will turn into a height equal to width.
If you know that the image have an aspect ratio of 1.25 then you could just set `padding-bottom: 80%;` since 100/1.25 is 80!

Comment: @Luke Excellent idea! The solution actually is: padding-bottom: 16.5%; I guess this is because it is the other way around - the 3px margin.